# Запуск внешнего приложения в форму

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi запустить приложения, допустим, калькулятор в форму приложения, в нете искал, но есть только под С, а надо делфи. Знает ли кто-нибудь как сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю из примера, главная форма запущенного приложения становится дочерней от формы запускающей программы и помещается в её главное окно. Видно, что при запуске программы её форма появляется как обычно, и только потом смещается в окно запустившей её программы.
По-видимому, используются стандартные функции библиотек Win32 или User32, остаётся только узнать их названия.

> > ща сам визио ставлю посматреть хочу

Зачем? Чтобы просмотреть исходник, достаточно блокнота.

Вот исходный код, в котором всё и происходит:

```
void PictureBox1Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //обработка клика по форме
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process bob = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                bob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                bob.StartInfo.Arguments += " /K TITLE Command Prompt";
                bob.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD"; //имя программы
                bob.Start(); //запускаем программу
        this.timer1.Enabled = true; //запускаем таймер
    }

    void Timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //обработка тика таймера
    {
        System.IntPtr winParent;
        System.IntPtr x;
        System.IntPtr winHandle = Usr32.FindWin("ConsoleWindowClass", "Command Prompt"); //находим окно, которое запустили
        if(winHandle != System.IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            winParent = Usr32.GetParent(winHandle);
            x = Usr32.SetParent(winHandle, this.pictureBox1.Handle); //присваиваем форме приложения в качестве родителя форму нашей программы
            x = Usr32.SetWindowPos(winHandle, 1, 10, 10, 500, 300, 0); //устанавливаем новую позицию этой формы, которая уже считается дочерней
            this.timer1.Enabled = false; //вырубаем таймер
        }
```

Сейчас попробую переписать на Delphi...
Вот, получилось очень просто и компактно:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject); //при клике на форме
var h:hwnd;     //указатель на окно
begin
//запускаем стандартную "командную строку"
  ShellExecute(form1.Handle,'open','cmd.exe',nil,'c:\\windows\system32\',SW_SHOW);
  sleep(10); //ждём, пока окно не появится
  //находим окно по заголовку
  h:=findwindow(nil, 'c:\\windows\system32\cmd.exe');
  //если нашли, присваиваем ему статус дочернего от нашего окошка
  if h<>0 then windows.SetParent(h,form1.Handle);
end;
```

Для ShellExecute (shell32.dll) нужно подключить модуль ShellAPI, а вот функции findwindow и setparent объявлены в модуле windows (win32.dll и user32.dll).
[Скачать мой пример](http://rghost.ru/23591411)
Кстати, прикольно получилось: на C написано до фига кода, а на Delphi - всего-то пара строчек, а результат тот же, может быть, даже лучше. :D

Comment: Приложение запускается не в форме, а в своем окне(((

Comment: Значит, слишком маленькая пауза. Можно в sleep написать, например, 100 миллисекунд, или вообще 1000. Видно, у тебя программа cmd.exe запускается слишком медленно, и findwindow срабатывает раньше времени, следовательно, не обнаруживает окно...
Ладно, можно попробовать так, как сделано в примере на C - запускать таймер, и уже он будет обнаруживать окно.
Вот, исправление: в процедуру клика по форме вставляем код активации таймера, строчки "h:=f..." и "if h..." переносим в обработчик таймера, и добавляем в него выключение, если h<>0...
Вот новая ссылка: http://rghost.ru/23666461

Comment: Для большей наглядности, вот немного другой пример. Вводишь путь программы и её заголовок в поля - приложение запускается и переносится в окно. Только вместо shellexecute используется winexec, кстати, он описан в модуле windows, поэтому не нужно подключать дополнительных модулей. Скачать: http://rghost.ru/23670601

Comment: ...Только нужно потом убивать открытые приложения, а то их процессы (без окон) будут всё время висеть в системе...

Comment: Воооо то что хотел)) теперь осталось разобраться как оно работает.... А как теперь изменять свойства формы в форме)))?

Comment: Работает просто: запускаем приложение, ищем открывшуюся форму по типу и/или заголовку, делаем её дочерью нашего окна (т.е. устанавливаем её родителем наше окно).
FindWindow - найти окно, эта функция возвращает указатель на окно. Дальше можно использовать этот указатель в функциях sendmessage и postmessage, т.е. отправлять форме сообщения о том, что она должна изменить что-то в себе. Кажется, можно даже менять компоненты на этой форме. Только при поиске формы нужно учитывать, что она уже не самостоятельная, а дочерняя... Тут я не уверен, как делать. Хотя можно использовать старый указатель.

Comment: Спс буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта фраза совсем непонятна:

> калькулятор в форму приложения

А запуск внешнего приложения из программы на Delphi - при помощи `ShellExecute ();`

Comment: Вот, допустим, есть прога написанная на делфи, там есть кнопка, её жмешь и приложение запускается в форме делфи.

Comment: Не встречал, да и зачем?

Comment: Да вот встретил и интересно стало)

Comment: Если не сложно киньте линк на пример на С посмотрю, возможно и delphi прикрутим, хотя пока практического применения данному сабжу не вижу.

Comment: Линка нет но вот один пример на сайте одном видел ща сам визио ставлю посматреть хочу
http://narod.yandex.ru/disk/26793186001/picBoxApp.7z

Comment: вот нашел 
http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=931&mode=show